# Извлечь последний элемент множества

Tags: c++, c++17

Как извлечь последний элемент `std::set`?

Пытаюсь так, но выдаёт ошибку:

```
std::set<int> x = {1,2,3};
x.extract(x.crbegin());
```

Comment: `x.extract(--(x.end()));`

Comment: Вы точно хотите извлечь, а не использовать? :) Предположу, что Вам нужно просто `int a = *x.rbegin();`

Answer (score 1):

Ну, все-таки `reverse_iterator` - не обычный итератор, так что для его применения следует использовать значение, на которое он указывает:

```
x.extract(*x.crbegin());
```

правда. У этого решения есть и минус - дополнительный поиск для извлечения.

Второй вариант вам указал @VTT - использовать прямой итератор:

```
x.extract(--(x.end()));
```